# multiple values in one cell in CSV files

Tags: csv, awk

I have CSV files with data format like following :

```
201212998474|201212998474|99|20140911092720|1410427640|Sy-module-1.PTS-DR1.mobinil.net;1410427618;0;10.56.201.79|2001|||0|||||mobinildpi|SOCIAL|||0|DIAMETER_LOGOUT||0,0,0,5634026,|201212998474NonRoaming,201212998474_2190_MONTHLY_1GB_20LE,201212998474_7702_Unlimited_CAP,201212998474_7702_POST_FUP_USAGE,|10||T|1|||||
201212998474|201212998474|99|20140911092720|1410427640|Sy-module-1.PTS-DR1.mobinil.net;1410427618;0;10.56.201.79|2001|||0|||||mobinildpi|EMAIL|||0|DIAMETER_LOGOUT||0,0,0,5634026,|201212998474NonRoaming,201212998474_2190_MONTHLY_1GB_20LE,201212998474_7702_Unlimited_CAP,201212998474_7702_POST_FUP_USAGE,|10||T|1|||||
201212998474|201212998474|99|20140911092720|1410427640|Sy-module-1.PTS-DR1.mobinil.net;1410427618;0;10.56.201.79|2001|||0|||||mobinildpi|STREAMING|||0|DIAMETER_LOGOUT||0,0,0,5634026,|201212998474NonRoaming,201212998474_2190_MONTHLY_1GB_20LE,201212998474_7702_Unlimited_CAP,201212998474_7702_POST_FUP_USAGE,|10||T|1|||||
201212998474|201212998474|99|20140911092720|1410427640|Sy-module-1.PTS-DR1.mobinil.net;1410427618;0;10.56.201.79|2001|||0|||||mobinildpi|WEB|||10180|DIAMETER_LOGOUT||0,0,0,5634026,|201212998474NonRoaming,201212998474_2190_MONTHLY_1GB_20LE,201212998474_7702_Unlimited_CAP,201212998474_7702_POST_FUP_USAGE,|10||T|1|||||
201212998474|201212998474|99|20140911092720|1410427640|Sy-module-1.PTS-DR1.mobinil.net;1410427618;0;10.56.201.79|2001|||0|||||mobinildpi|IM_AND_VOIP|||0|DIAMETER_LOGOUT||0,0,0,5634026,|201212998474NonRoaming,201212998474_2190_MONTHLY_1GB_20LE,201212998474_7702_Unlimited_CAP,201212998474_7702_POST_FUP_USAGE,|10||T|1|||||
201212998474|201212998474|99|20140911092720|1410427640|Sy-module-1.PTS-DR1.mobinil.net;1410427618;0;10.56.201.79|2001|||0|||||mobinildpi|DEFAULT|||0|DIAMETER_LOGOUT||0,0,0,5634026,|201212998474NonRoaming,201212998474_2190_MONTHLY_1GB_20LE,201212998474_7702_Unlimited_CAP,201212998474_7702_POST_FUP_USAGE,|10||T|1|||||
201212998474|201212998474|99|20140911092720|1410427640|Sy-module-1.PTS-DR1.mobinil.net;1410427618;0;10.56.201.79|2001|||0|||||mobinildpi|TUNNELING|||0|DIAMETER_LOGOUT||0,0,0,5634026,|201212998474NonRoaming,201212998474_2190_MONTHLY_1GB_20LE,201212998474_7702_Unlimited_CAP,201212998474_7702_POST_FUP_USAGE,|10||T|1|||||
201212998474|201212998474|99|20140911092720|1410427640|Sy-module-1.PTS-DR1.mobinil.net;1410427618;0;10.56.201.79|2001|||0|||||mobinildpi|FREETRAFFIC|||0|DIAMETER_LOGOUT||0,0,0,5634026,|201212998474NonRoaming,201212998474_2190_MONTHLY_1GB_20LE,201212998474_7702_Unlimited_CAP,201212998474_7702_POST_FUP_USAGE,|10||T|1|||||
201212998474|201212998474|99|20140911092720|1410427640|Sy-module-1.PTS-DR1.mobinil.net;1410427618;0;10.56.201.79|2001|||0|||||mobinildpi|ALWAYS_ON|||0|DIAMETER_LOGOUT||0,0,0,5634026,|201212998474NonRoaming,201212998474_2190_MONTHLY_1GB_20LE,201212998474_7702_Unlimited_CAP,201212998474_7702_POST_FUP_USAGE,|10||T|1|||||
```

i need to extract the 4 values in the 22th column each and get the difference between the first reading and the last reading  for each of them  in the column  .
i am trying this code :

```
awk -F "|" '{
if (length(msisdn[$1] == 0)) {
                           msisdn[$1] = $6 ;
                           counter[$1] = $22 ; }
last[$1] = $22 ;
type[$1] = $23  ;
                              } END { for ( i in msisdn ) { print i " : " msisdn[i] " : " type[i] " : " (counter [i]-last[i]) ; }}' 201409* > counters.txt
```

but it gives me the the desired out for the first value in the column only .
The expected output should something like this :

```
201274971010 : Sy-ptsd-3.module-3.PTS1-DRC.mobinil.net;1410748407;0;10.215.43.213 : 201274971010NonRoaming,201274971010_2190_MONTHLY_1GB_20LE, : 0 , 320 
201202999478 : Sy-ptsd-3.module-8.PTS3-DRC.mobinil.net;1410753394;0;10.141.241.65 : 201202999478NonRoaming,201202999478_2190_MONTHLY_1GB_20LE, : 0 , 150
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you're trying to do here. Can you try to explain more clearly? How are the columns grouped? What is the significance of $6 and $23? Perhaps you could reduce the number of columns in your question, as it seems that many of them are unrelated to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short (shortest!) answer is

```
awk -F\| '{
              # split(source, destination, separator_re)
              split($22, values, /,/);
              print values[4]-values[1];
          }'
```

I think that you can arrange for the rest of the output file requirements (that I can't understand)

Comment: ps: see the above comment by @Tom Fenech that explains my problems trying to understand your requirements...

Comment: Thanks for your answer it was helpful enough sorry if i am not clear enough in my explanation

Comment: Dear Mohamed, the problem in your explanation was that your problem IS a complicated problem, that you've solved on your own for 98%, and you left all that complication in your question.  If you make the effort (I understand that it is an effort) to drop all the complications and present a simpler problem it is much more likely to have useful answers!